# string comparison between two strings in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using below code for checking whether two strings content are equal or not but it is not working as i am using watson explorer id

```
<xsl:variable name="str1" select="./td[4]"/>
<xsl:variable name="str2" select="./td[2]"/>

<xsl:if test="$str1 = $str2">
  true 
</xsl:if>
```

please tell me how to find using xslt whether the content of two strings are equal or not as i was trying by using compare(str1,str2) but it was also not
working for me as i am using  xslt 1.0 verson

Comment: Please post enough code for us to reproduce the problem. Don't say "it is not working"; tell us what is your expected result and what do you actually get.

Comment: Don't tell us that something "isn't working". Tell us how it fails. Downvoting.

Comment: thanks Michael now my problem is solved actualy i was comparing two strings  with = operator so for same content it was giving false  when i start debug  in tool i found that in one of the string there was one space added in the beginning due to which it was returning false while comparing it with other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML:

```
<Sample>`<AccountName1>SREE</AccountName1>`<AccountName2>SREE</AccountName2>`<SortCode>789-88-8907</SortCode>`<CardNumber>4545-6767-9876-8764</CardNumber>`<address>j-89-8999</address>`</Sample>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match = "*[local-name()='AccountName1' or local-name()='AccountName2']">
    <xsl:variable name = "var1">
 <xsl:value-of select = "/*[local-name()='Sample']/*[local-name()='AccountName1']/text()"/>
  </xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name = "var2">
 <xsl:value-of select = "/*[local-name()='Sample']/*[local-name()='AccountName2']/text()"/>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> First: <xsl:value-of select = "$var1"/> </xsl:message>
         <xsl:message dp:priority="debug"> Second: <xsl:value-of select = "$var2"/> </xsl:message>
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test = "$var1=$var2">
<xsl:message dp:priority = "debug">Both are same </xsl:message>
                <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:value-of select = "."/>
            </xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message dp:priority = "debug">Both are different </xsl:message>
                <xsl:copy>
<xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace(*[local-name()='AccountName2'],'','',$var1)"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 


</xsl:stylesheet>
```